# How is calculated arccos (or arctan, or arcsin)?

Tags: trigonometry

Let be

- $O(0,0)$, $I(1,0)$ and $J(0,1)$
- a point $M$ so that $||\vec{OM}||=1$
- a point $C(\cos\widehat{MOI},0)=(x_M,0)$
- a point $S(0, \sin\widehat{MOI})=(0,y_M)$

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the value of the angle $\alpha = \widehat{IOM}$, having the cosinus $\cos\alpha$ given.

for $ x = \cos \alpha $ I can find

- $\sin \alpha = k.\sqrt{1-\cos²x}, k\in\{-1;1\}$
- $\tan \alpha = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$
- $CI = 1-\cos\alpha$
- the chord $IM$ length $=\sqrt{CI^2+\sin^2\alpha}$

From that chord length I thought I would be able to calculate $\alpha$ (= the arc length) but it looks like there is no formula...

Then I thought the slope of $(OM)$ ($=\tan\alpha$) would help me since the angle is the same concept as the slope and then directly linked. But there's apparenty no formula either, I found that $\arctan$, like $\arccos$ and $\arcsin$ are implemented with complicated algorithms that return results with a relative precision but don't return exact results.

I don't know if my question has an answer, but why is it not possible to *simply* find $\alpha$ with all that data ? That seems simple at first thought...

Comment: How do you define $\sin(M)$ and $\cos(M)$ for a _point_ $M$ ?

Comment: What do you mean ? M is a point so has no sinus nor cosinus.

Comment: Then what do you mean by $C(\cos(M),0)$ and $S(0,\sin(M))$ ? I presume that you're referring to the endpoints of the projections of $\vec{OM}$ on the axes but it is a bit of abuse of notation to write it that way.

Comment: oh sorry I made a mistake, C is $(\cos\widehat{MOI},0)=(x_M,0)$ and $S$ is $(0, \sin\widehat{MOI})=(0,y_M)$. I correct it right now